# Craft 4, CKEditor 5, image resizeOptions not showing in image toolbar

Tags: craft4, ckeditor5

I'm experimenting with all the CKEditor 5 config options and I like how the docs have the image resize (https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/images/images-overview.html#image-contextual-toolbar)

[image: CKEditor docs]

Using the Image Config docs (https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_image_imageconfig-ImageConfig.html) my config is now:

```
{
  "image": {
    "resizeOptions": [
      {
        "icon": "original",
        "label": "Original size",
        "name": "resizeImage:original",
        "value": null
      },
      {
        "icon": "small",
        "label": "100px",
        "name": "resizeImage:100",
        "value": "100"
      },
      {
        "icon": "medium",
        "label": "200px",
        "name": "resizeImage:200",
        "value": "200"
      }
    ],
    "resizeUnit": "px",
    "toolbar": [
      "toggleImageCaption",
      "imageTextAlternative",
      "|",
      "resizeImage:100",
      "resizeImage:200",
      "resizeImage:original",
      "|",
      "linkImage"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have the other toolbar buttons but not the image resize buttons:

[image: my image CKEditor image toolbar]

It doesn't even have the extra separator. Have I typo'ed something?

Comment: Have just noticed browser console says "toolbarview-item-unavailable item: 'resizeImage:100'" and links to https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/support/error-codes.html#error-toolbarview-item-unavailable. Does resizeOptions (https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_image_imageconfig-ImageConfig.html#member-resizeOptions) need to be added as a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Craft had the answer all along
https://github.com/craftcms/ckeditor/discussions/94#discussioncomment-5920028

Answer (score 2):

try like this in this post on ckeditor github .. . https://github.com/craftcms/ckeditor/discussions/120

Comment: That link doesn't have any info about image resize. When I try that config I don't get "transformImage".